Docker container causes connection issues
I have a freshly installed Debian 12 system where I installed VirtualBox and Docker so far.
However when starting any Docker container, some seconds pass and I loose access to the entire server via any external means. I can still access it via LAN, strangely. Stopping the container makes everything go back to normal.
Anyway, I think I've isolated the issue to route problems.
When no Docker container is running, these are the routes:
ip route

default via 192.168.8.1 dev enp3s0 proto static
1.1.1.1 via 192.168.8.1 dev enp3s0
8.8.4.4 via 192.168.8.1 dev enp3s0
8.8.8.8 via 192.168.8.1 dev enp3s0
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
192.168.8.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.8.20
192.168.8.1 dev enp3s0 scope link

After some seconds with a Docker container running, the output changes to (and the connection breaks):
ip route

0.0.0.0 dev veth4b44de1 scope link
default dev veth4b44de1 scope link
1.1.1.1 via 192.168.8.1 dev enp3s0
8.8.4.4 via 192.168.8.1 dev enp3s0
8.8.8.8 via 192.168.8.1 dev enp3s0
169.254.0.0/16 dev veth4b44de1 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.234.169
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
192.168.8.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.8.20
192.168.8.1 dev enp3s0 scope link

Also note that the server sees the internet over a NAT, which is my Mikrotik router. Just putting this there in case it's important to the problem. As I said, LAN still works, over the Internet it breaks. What's strange, though, is that it only breaks if a Docker container is running, and does NOT break if I run any application directly, such as a demo python3 http server directly on the host system.
What can I do to remedy this issue? I've honestly never had such problems with Docker before. Any help is greatly appreciated!

What turned out to be the culprit was connman. It tries to manage the routes, and messes them up.
What ended up working was:
# Open '/etc/connman/main.conf', uncomment NetworkInterfaceBlacklist and change to:
NetworkInterfaceBlacklist = vmnet,vboxnet,docker,veth
# Restart connman daemon
systemctl restart connman.service

I also commented the very same on the Docker forums just to make sure.
